Get latest row based by date grouped by concat
I have an issue where I'm trying to retrieve the latest Date created row out of a ConCat column. But getting an error that it's an invalid name. So I'm guessing you can't do it this way?
Unworking Code:
     SELECT
 [USER ID],
 [GROUP ID],
 [DATE CREATED],
concat([USER ID], '_', [GROUP ID]) as CONCAT
         
  FROM [TABLE1]
     
  where
  [DATE CREATED] in ( SELECT MAX([DATE CREATED]) from [TABLE1] group by CONCAT)`


TABLE
enter image description here
RESULT NEEDED
enter image description here

Concat isn't at that point, you need to group byconcat([USER ID], '_', [GROUP ID]) or use a subquery

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

We don't post images of sample data or results here.

Please don't upload images, its better to show the columns and rows in data format.

The logic for the original query is likely wrong, anyway, becuase it might allow showing rows from one User ID/Group ID pair that happen to match the max Created Date from a different User ID/Group ID pair.
Instead, this may be a job for a windowing function
WITH Numbered As
(
    SELECT
        [USER ID],
        [GROUP ID],
        [DATE CREATED],
        row_number() over (Partition By [User ID], [Group ID] Order By [Date Created] DESC) rn         
    FROM [TABLE1]
)
SELECT
    [User ID],
    [Group ID],
    [Date Created],
    [USER ID] + '_' + [GROUP ID] as [Concat]
FROM Numbered
WHERE rn = 1

Or, you might be able to do this completely within a GROUP BY
SELECT
    [USER ID],
    [GROUP ID],
    MAX([DATE CREATED]) AS [Date Created],
    [USER ID] + '_' + [GROUP ID] as CONCAT        
FROM [TABLE1]
GROUP BY [User ID], [Group ID]     

But I suspect this is contrived for the question, and the actual query has more columns in play.

This works once I took out the ) in "[GROUP ID])"
But it's very slow, Do you know if there's a way to speed it up.
I'm pulling last 90 days and it roughly 5.6 Million it has to go through, should be less than 70k when finished

One option is to wait to do the concat until after the cte. Or, even better, let your client code or reporting tool handle the concatenation and only return the raw the user id and group id columns from the sql.

yea ad to cancel query it took 15 min to only find 10 entries, where I can load all 5.6 mil in 6 min

Yes, You are correct, you can't use the alias CONCAT in the WHERE clause like you are doing.
There is one way to solve your problem by using a Common Table Expression known as CTE, this will first create the concatenated column and then use the result query.
Here is an example:
WITH ConcatTable AS (
  SELECT
    [USER ID],
    [GROUP ID],
    [DATE CREATED],
    CONCAT([USER ID], '_', [GROUP ID]) AS CONCAT
  FROM [TABLE1]
)
SELECT
  [USER ID],
  [GROUP ID],
  [DATE CREATED],
  CONCAT
FROM ConcatTable
WHERE [DATE CREATED] IN (
  SELECT MAX([DATE CREATED])
  FROM ConcatTable
  GROUP BY CONCAT
)

I hope this will help you.

This could still give incorrect results, though, because it only matches the subquery based on date, and ignores user id/group id. This could allow for rows with the wrong user id and group id that happen to match the max created date from a different group.
